# Laptop's removable battery has 4 18650 3.7v cells in series, can I attach 8 more as external battery pack as 4s2p?

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, laptop, bms

I have 4 years old HP gaming laptop with removable battery. I never kept the battery in the laptop. Right since the purchase, I stored the battery in a sealed pack in cold place, and charged it to 45% every 30-40 days.

I run the laptop via its charger which is connected to a PC UPS always. After power outage, laptop runs for around 30 minutes only on the UPS.

I wish to make a PORTABLE battery pack.

I have to attend long zoom meetings, on sometimes there are power outages. I wish to extend the original battery without changing the 18650 batteries inside it. I am planning to attach wires to the end terminals of these 4 18650 cells to attach a battery pack of 4s2p in parallel.

Do I need to cut the supply between the laptop battery's 18650 and the external pack? Or I can keep them all in parallel without any risk or loss of power?

If I have to cut off the supply, I was planning to do the following:
I know if the BMS detects 0 voltage, it will lock the battery. So I was planning on using 2 switches for this setup. 1st switch will allow the laptop battery to get parallel connection from the external pack (effectively having a 3s4p battery pack). Then few seconds after that, I will flick 2nd switch which will cut off the supply between laptop battery's 18650 and the BMS so as to keep only the external pack connected with the BMS.

Question 1) Is it practical, safe or efficient?

Question 2) What will happen if I switch to external pack ON THE FLY, while laptop is on and working? Will it show higher battery percentage immediately, or I will have to perform restart/standby to update it? I know for a fact that I ALWAYS remove the battery while the laptop is connected to the charger and working, it instantly shows no battery and I didn't face any problems due to that ever.

P.S. I am here to learn and only studied electricals till high school, I know the basics only so please don't start bashing! I will buy genuine Samsung 18650 batteries for the external pack, not cheap chinese ones.

Comment: Use the original battery plus the UPS and if you need more capacity get a larger UPS.

Comment: @SolarMike Please elaborate, I can see you are a lecturer and have a huge reputation.
Kindly explain why do you feel it's better to use a UPS? A UPS won't provide portability, I will have to keep the laptop stationary. Whereas  I can carry the external battery pack easily in a backpack anywhere.

Comment: You did not ask for portability.

Comment: Check the HP battery pack - it will most likely have a multi-way connector connecting it to the laptop.  That's so that the laptop can monitor each cell individually.  Connecting an external battery pack will be harder than you think.

Comment: Most laptops have fairly complex interaction with their battery and will probably shut down (and may leave diagnostic information in the battery's own BMS) if they detect abnormal conditions. So this is probably not going to work and may make the existing battery useless. Hence Mike's comment : use a UPS.